# Probability of getting cancer from 10 moles

Tags: probability

I stumbled upon an question which I can't wrap my head around. The case is as follows: A patient comes to the doctor and has, let's say 10 moles on his body. Each mole has a 5% chance of giving the patient skin cancer within a year. What is the probabilty the patient will get skin cancer within a year?

Thanks!
John

Comment: Well, If you assume that each mole turns cancerous independently of all the others, it's easier to compute the complement.  What's the probability that none of the $10$ moles turn cancerous?

Comment: Well, the probabilty of not getting cancer from one mole would be 0,95. Do I just multiply this probabilty for each mole? So the probabilty of getting cancer would be 1 - 0,95^10 = 0,4 ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to compute the chance of not getting cancer and subtract from $1$.  What is the chance of not getting cancer from one mole?

Comment: Well, the probabilty of not getting cancer from one mole would be 0,95. Do I just multiply this probabilty for each mole? So the probabilty of getting cancer would be 1 - 0,95^10 = 0,4 ?